# Track dynamic button with href and target_blank

Tags: php, onclick, tracking, target

I need to track every time a user clicks on a dynamic button. Also I need to know what product is he clicking. Now I have this button:

```
<div class="buy">
    <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $this->product['from']; ?>">
        <img src="http://example.com/data/images/buy.jpg" alt="buy">
    </a>
</div>
```

Href sends the user to another site to buy the product. How can i track this on PHP?

Comment: you can try to work with javascript and send a ajax request somewhere when someone clicks a link, or see website traffic logs and filter pages by products, hits etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `href` is linking to another page that is not on your own server, you can go with an ajax-solution, like @coder1984 proposed, or you can create a proxy php script. That means:

- the user clicks the link to the proxy, sending in the product URL

  - like: `href="myproxy.php?url=<?php echo $this->product['from']; ?>"`
- the proxy gets the URL, checks it and updates a database, the session, a text file
- afterwards it redirects the user to the actual URL

Comment: I have done the proxy/redirect in the past, and it has worked quite well.  It also avoids the potential inconsistencies relating to your AJAX requests not completing before the browser leaves the page, which can really throw off your counts.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side dynamic user actions can be determined using Javascript/Jquery. Here's how its done in Jquery,

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.buy').click(function(){
          alert('This is clicked');
         });
     });
```

To track in PHP, you can pass the value(buttons clicked) to PHP using Jquery AJAX. Here's the [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).